# MDX: how to get a formatted attribute value?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a slight problem with an MDX query in SSAS, MSSQL 2012.

Let's say we have a [Products] dimension. In this dimension there is a [Business Number] attribute with AttributeHierarchyEnabled set to false. It only depends on the primary key named [Product]. I would like to get the business number in a query (for example sales by product). I know two ways how to do it:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[BusinessNumber]
AS [Products].[Product].currentmember.properties("Business Number")
SELECT [Measures].[BusinessNumber] ON 0
...
```

or

```
...
[Products].[Product].ALLMEMBERS
DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Products].[Product].[Business Number]
ON 1
...
```

But I would also like to get the value formatted. The Business Number should always have six digits (with leading zeroes).

I know how to format it manually:

```
...
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[BusinessNumber]
AS [Products].[Product].currentmember.properties("Business Number", TYPED),
FORMAT_STRING="000000"
...
```

But I don't like the idea of fixing the format in the query. I have the same format string set in the dimension editor - in attribute properties I have FormatString set to 000000. But it seems to be ignored.

So the final question is: Is there a way how to use properties function and/or keyword to get a formatted value of an attribute? Is there any other way?

Related question is: Can I get a key of an attribute instead of it's value? Or can I get it's format string?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get what you want would be the way that also worked in older SSAS versions: Add a column to the dimension on the relational side (e. g. in the data source view or in a view on the dimension table that you use as the base for the dimension, you do not need to physically add this to the dimension table) that has a character data type and contains the formatted value. Then configure this as the name column for your attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this alternative. But it seems to be more of a workaround than a solution. Is there really no way to access key/formatted value/... of an attribute with disabled hiearchy?

Answer (score 0):

To get the key use:
 [Products].[Product].currentmember.member_key

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, [Product].currentmember.member_key would give me the key of the Product attribute, which isn't what I am trying to achieve. I would like to get the key of the [Business Number] attribute instead.